# libgdx god's ray shader effect blending function

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader, blending

I am trying to create a god's ray effect from scratch using libgdx and opengl shader langage. To do this I use a background image as light source, then I apply another texture as a mask setting the spriteBatch color to full black.

background texture

[image: original image]

mask texture

[image: mask]

the mask is then rendered in full black over the background

[image: mask over background]

```
    Color batchColor = batch.getColor();
    fbo1.begin();
        batch.begin();
            batch.draw(textureBackground, 0, 0, w, h);
            batch.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            batch.draw(textureBar, 0, 0, w, h);
            batch.setColor(batchColor);
        batch.end();
    fbo1.end();
```

then the god's ray shader is applied

[image: rendered ray]

```
Sprite rayEffect = new Sprite(fbo1.getColorBufferTexture());
rayEffect.flip(false, true);

fbo2.begin();
    batch.setShader(shaderGodRay);
    batch.begin();
        rayEffect.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
    batch.setShader(null);
fbo2.end();
```

The rays are ok at this stage. Know I would like to blend the original mask color with the rendered rays in order to obtain the final image. Only rendering the mask again on top of the rays are totally overlapped by the colored mask

[image: with color]

```
    rayEffect = new Sprite(fbo2.getColorBufferTexture());
    rayEffect.flip(false, true);

    batch.begin();
        rayEffect.draw(batch);
        batch.draw(textureBar, 0, 0, w, h);
    batch.end();
```

I think alpha blending should do the trick, but on my ray rendered image, the opacity is full.
Does someone know how I may blend the two texture together in order to obtain the desired final result?

Comment: You will have to modify the opacity in your masked image. When you apply the mask, set opacity everywhere to 0 where the mask appears. To compose the final image, render first the colored-mask, than alphablend the god-ray image over it with GL_SOURCE_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA. I do not add this as answer, since I don't know how this works exactly with libgdx

Comment: Why not draw the rayEffect _after_ the textureBar in the last code snippet?  Within the first two code snippets, you draw the bars (black) first then follow that with drawing the rayEffect ... but in the last snippet, you draw the ray and then the bars afterward; why not switch those two statements?

Comment: @BDL seems a good idea, but do you know how I can slice a transparent shape based on my mask on the background texture?

Comment: @Bret the ray effect as a full opaque black, so it will hide the colored shapes.

Comment: I'm not sure what method you're using to create your effect texture. Typically, you would start with rendering just the light source (the sun), not the whole background scene. (Although you could get a similar effect by rendering the background scene with high contrast.) Then when you are done processing the effect, you could draw it additively over your background + mask without worrying about opacity. The added benefit over your method is that your frame buffers can be much smaller than the screen, since you don't have to preserve background detail, just blurred stuff.

Comment: Super late answer, you are totally right, I did not really understand the way to create this effect at this time. Keeping this question unresolved until I had time to write a an example. The main problem here was that I used an image as the light source instead of a plain light.